# Overide connection string at dtexec

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Hi i have simple job ssis package with connection sqlserver "windows authentication"

I need to execute package using dtexec with new connection sqlserver use sql authentication. Can i override connection ssis package from windows authentication to sql authentication ?

I already try sample dtexec below :

dtexec /File F:\testpackage.dtsx /CONN "Source"\;"\"Data Source=myserver;User ID=myuser;Initial Catalog=mydb;Password=mypassword\""

But connection can't override still read connection windows authentication

Comment: What you have there looks correct.  Could you provide the exact error message that you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

Use [dtexecui](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/packages/execute-package-utility-dtexecui-ui-reference?view=sql-server-ver15) to visually configure the command line:

> The Execute Package Utility is a graphical user interface for the
> DTExec command prompt tool. The user interface makes it easy to
> configure options and it automatically assembles the command line that
> is passed to the DTExec command prompt tool when you run the package
> from the specified options.
>
> **The Execute Package Utility can also be used to assemble command lines
> that you use when running DTExec directly.**

Comment: Thanks for response. Error description : "Login Failed for User NTDXXX\USER". Just info main question is can i override connection at ssis package with windows authentication to sql authentication using script dtexec whitout reconfigure connection manager at ssis package directly